# Using SAML or OAuth to allow one web application to retrieve user's data from another application

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, identity, saml

I'm developing two web applications, which will be run by different parties, but share many users.  When user U is logged in to App A, I'd like App A to be able to fetch U's data from App B as well.  So, App A needs to be able to tell App B "User U is logged on and trusts me to fetch his data - can you please send it to me".

I'm not sure how to do authentication for this.  I imagine it could be done via SAML or OAuth.  What is the appropriate way for App A to prove to App B that User U has logged on and wants App B to send over his data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use saml authentication mechanism with federation server. Let's say you have two SPs( App A and App B) connected with one federation server(IDP with LDAP or ADFS). When user tries to access APP A  then user will be redirected to IDP server login page and return saml token response on successful authentication. Now User tries to access App B then It will get all user info from SAML token generated for App A. Because App B is already added in IDP server's trusted party so user need not to provide credentials for authentication.

You can refer this [link](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) to start with. Please let me know for any help/query.

Git repo [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml)